# Unable to dismiss view from observer methods at In-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an application using in-app purchases.
Clicking a button in the main view controller loads a second view controller with restore purchases, buy product and cancel. There is a delegate protocol to dismiss the view.
When i clic cancel it works fine, but if I set the dismiss programatically in any of the store observer methods it doesn't work. Via NSNotification it seems to work but I want to know why it is not working. Also trying to change a button's alpha value from there doesn't work.
Thank you in advance.

Appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StoreNavigationController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  StoreNavigationController* observer;
@end
```

Appdelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize observer;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    observer = [[StoreNavigationController alloc] init];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "storeNavigationController.h"

@class completeView;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <StoreNavigationControllerDelegate>
- (void)storeNavigationControllerDidFinish;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"storeView"]) {
 [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];

     }
 }

- (void)storeNavigationControllerDidFinish
{
    [self updateView];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
//There is also a method in this file launching [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"storeView" sender:self];
```

storeNavigationController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "plistController.h"

@protocol StoreNavigationControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)storeNavigationControllerDidFinish; //View dismisser
@end

@class StoreNavigationController;
@interface StoreNavigationController : UIViewController <SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <StoreNavigationControllerDelegate> delegate;
//User actions
- (IBAction)restoreItems:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)buyItem:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)cancelPurchase:(UIButton *)sender;

//Methods SKPaymentTransactionObserver 
- (void) completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void) failedTransaction:  (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions;
@end
```

storeNavigationController.m

```
- (IBAction)cancelPurchase:(UIButton *)sender {
[self.delegate storeNavigationControllerDidFinish]; //this one works ok
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                [self.delegate storeNavigationControllerDidFinish]; //Any of those calls in the switch doesn't work.
                break;
             case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                [self.delegate storeNavigationControllerDidFinish];
                break;
             case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                [self.delegate storeNavigationControllerDidFinish];
             default:
                break;
         }
     }
  }

 - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue removedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions       {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction* transaction in transactions) {
         NSLog(@"Transacción eliminada de la cola: %@", transaction.description);
     }
           [self.delegate storeNavigationControllerDidFinish]; //Not working

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegates should be using the assign property.

```
 @property (assign, nonatomic) id <StoreNavigationControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

But that might not be your issue. Have you tried calling the delegate method before completing the transaction or restoring the transaction. Have you set a breakpoint or used NSLog to check to see if the delegate is not nil before calling those methods?

```
NSLog(@"delegate: %@", self.delegate);
```